# How can I save notes taken in the Galaxy Ace's Notes 2.0 application to restore after a system reset?

Tags: backup, samsung-galaxy-ace, notes

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830 running 2.3.3 and I took a lot of notes in the default Notes 2.0 application. I want to reset the system and I need to back them up somehow before I perform the reset.

Comment: There is no "default" notes app in vanilla Android that I am aware of. What device are you using?

Comment: @eldarerathis Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830

Answer (score 2):

Install [Titanium backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&feature=search_result) - (this requires root access) from Play store and you can backup thinks like sms/call logs/apps and app data. In your case, you might want to backup the app and the app data for that particular app, save your backups. Once you restore the phone, you can use Titanium to restore that app and data.